# Higher-order ODEs as first-order ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

"A second order ODE that lives in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is a first-order ODE that lives in $\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$". I don't understand this point and I think I'm missing some basic ideas here. Can someone fill me in? I was going through [this(section 3.3)](https://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/AlexanderSchekochihin/ODE/2018/ODELectureNotes.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

It's just a trick. Consider this ODE:

$$ y^{(n)}= f ( y, y'', \dots, y^{(n-1)} ).$$

This is a $n$-th order ODE in $\mathbb{R}$. Now, if you define $Y$ as:

$$Y=(y, y', y'', \dots, y^{(n-1)})$$

it's easy to see that you can write

$$Y' = F( Y) \text{ with } F: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^n .$$

i.e. making it of order 1. Indeed

$$ F(x_1, x_2 , \dots , x_n)= (x_2 , x_3, \dots, x_n, f(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)).$$

Sometimes this can help in dealing with a higher order ODE, especially if it's linear. Check "wronskian" online for a general treatment of this. In your case, I guess by reasoning like this componentwise you can conclude.

Forgetting about the $+1$ on both sides (it's just the time), consider

$$ \begin{cases}
y_1 '' = f_1 (y_1, \dots, y_n, y_1 ', \dots, y_n ')\\
y_2 ''= f_2 (y_1, \dots, y_n, y_1 ', \dots , y_n ')\\
...\\
y_n '' = f_n ( y_1, \dots, y_n, y_1 ', \dots , y_n ')
\end{cases}$$

Set $Y= (y_1, y_1 ', y_2 , y_2 ', \dots, y_n , y_n ')$. Then the system above can be rewritten as

$$
Y' = F(Y)
$$

with $F: \mathbb{R}^{2n} \to \mathbb{R}^{2n}$, because if $j$ is odd, then $F_j (x_1, \dots, x_{2n})= x_{j+1}$ (check the definition of $Y$ to understand why it's like this. When you differentiate the $j$-th component of $Y$ you get the $(j+1)$-th). Instead, the even components are $F_{2j} (x_1, \dots, x_{2n})= f_j (x_1 , x_3 , \dots, x_{2n-1}, x_2 ,\dots, x_{2n})$. Maybe I could have chosen a better definition for $Y$, but if you substitute $(x_1, \dots, x_{2n})$ with $Y$ you see it (should) work out. So it's a first order system in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$.

Comment: I'm confused with the $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$ part

Comment: @Nandu : It is perhaps more familiar if written as $\Bbb R\times \Bbb R^n$ and $\Bbb R\times \Bbb R^{2n}$. The state vector of the second-order system has $n$ compontents, so building the enhanced state for the first order system by adding the first derivatives makes $2n$ components.